# Some Ethash PoW questions

Tags: ethash

I've downloaded the Etash source code and did some test on the PoW algorithm. 
In **MinerAux.h**, if the `current.seedHash != newSeedHash`, the DAG file needs to be regenerated. And the `newSeedHash` was set by the rpc-client method `getEthashWork` (in **EthashClient.cpp**).
I am confused by the  method `getEthashWork`. I have some questions below:

1. How to compute the three parameters “hash without seal, seed hash, target boundary"?
2. When will the seed hash be different from current one?
3. Which conditions will lead to the seed hash changing?